# Mocha describe is not defined

Tags: node.js, windows-7, mocha.js

I have a directory called MochaTests. Inside there I have the example test found on the mocha website "1.2.3 Mocha". At the command prompt (My OS is WIN7), I type in Mocha, and the result is `0 passing(2 m2)`. I installed just like the instructions say: `npm install -g mocha` from what I can tell it installs just fine

So, in `c:\MochaTests>` I type `node` then I type `.load test1.js`  I get

`ReferenceError: describe is not defined.`

On the nodejs googlegroup there is a post dated 2012-12-24 that is titled "describe is not defined"... they claims this "solved my problems", but did not provide any details about what he did to clear up this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tl;dr

You'll want to run `mocha` instead of `node`:

#### Install Mocha (globally)

`npm install mocha -g`

#### Then, run mocha

`mocha`

OLD (the post has since been removed):

This post says to use mocha instead of node in your command which works for me:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/58313

Comment: Thanks @Chris. What if I want to run the tests via node. Is this possible? How?

Comment: For using node instead of mocha, someone else had an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33222730/2246213

Comment: Have tried many alternates got from internet but getting the same error.

Comment: This answer is nothing but a broken link

Comment: @Kickaha - thanks for pointing that out. I updated it with the solution. I just didn't want to poach a solution from another site when I posted that a few years ago.