# ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I am trying to run test for graphql endpoint using [gest](https://github.com/mfix22/gest).  Below is my code

```js
const Gest = require('graphicli')
const schema = require('./path/schema.js')

const gest = Gest(schema, {
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:7770/graphql',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
})

describe('GraphQL', () => {
  test('{getAllNominator{firstName}}', () => {
    return gest('{getAllNominator{firstName}}').then(({ data, errors }) => {
      expect(errors).toBeUndefined()
      expect(data).toEqual('Adam')
    })
  })
})
```

But I am getting the following error

> ReferenceError: describe is not defined

As per the solution give in [Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400459/referenceerror-describe-is-not-defined-nodejs) I ran the file using *mocha*.  But it the gives another error

> ReferenceError: test is not defined

I am stuck here. How can I solve this issue. And also one more question. Is *gest* and *mocha* related?
Please some one help me out of this

Comment: how do you run it? which command do you use?

Comment: i ranit using mocha command. mocha test.js

Answer (score 2):

`describe` function is setup by mocha.

If you have installed `mocha` locally, run test with

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha path/to/test.js
```

Or

```
mocha path/to/test.js
```

Also, you might want to replace `test(...)` call with `it(...)`

Comment: As I told before i ran it with mocha. But I got another error ReferenceError: test is not defined

Comment: @SVP, you have to require `expect` in that file.

Comment: Do you mean expect from 'chai'?

Comment: @SVP, sorry I am not sure. I use `should` mostly.

Comment: But then it becomes a test run using mocha. Here i want to implement gest testing

Answer (score 0):

Discussion for this is happening [here](https://github.com/mfix22/gest/issues/7). Basically you need to run the posted example in an environment that has `describe` as a global, like [Mocha][3] and [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/).