# nodejs + jest : ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

The [Jest documentation on Globals](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api) says the following (emphasis mine).

> In your test files, Jest puts each of these methods and objects into the global environment. *You don't have to require or import anything to use them*. However, if you prefer explicit imports, you can do import {describe, expect, it} from '@jest/globals'.

So, why does typing `jest` or `npm test` with `scripts.test` (in `package.json`) pointing to `jest --verbose` cause the `ReferenceError: describe is not defined` error? Some of the questions around this on SO and elsewhere, mention that, `jest` should be installed globally, installed with `--save-dev`, referred to local `node_modules`, etc. None of them work.

What am I missing?

This is my `index.spec.js`.

```js
function checkArgs(args) {
  if (args.length > 4) {
    // Error message on extraneous parameters
    return false
  } else if (args.length < 4) {
    // Error message on insufficient parameters
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

describe("Arguments check", () => {
  test("Number of arguments should be 4", () => {
    expect(checkArgs(process.argv)).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: That piece of code you posted is okay. Do you have a custom jest configuration?
Jest should be installed locally. Also, try removing `node_modules` directory and try a new install.

Comment: I tried `jest init` too. Didn't help.

Comment: I was able to get this working with `const {describe, expect, test} = require( '@jest/globals')` at the top of the file. :roll-eyes:

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28400459/22161745